# android alert dialog showing WindowManager$ BadTokenException

Tags: android

I have implemented the below code to show custom alert dialog but when i call this dialog it is showing exception:

WindowManager.BadTokenException

```
public static void showAlertDialog(final String title, String message,
            final Context context, final boolean redirectToPreviousScreen) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertbox.setMessage(message);
        alertbox.setTitle(title);

        alertbox.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

            }
        });
        try{
            alertbox.show();    
        }catch (Exception b) {

        }
```

Comment: Hi to all it's done, the problem was alertdialog was not getting activity context.

Comment: Good to hear. You can post the answer for yourself and accept it. This is recommended behaviour.